# How to print to the stdout / stderr from an emacs graphical session?

Tags: debugging

I'd like to print into the terminal that started emacs, instead of using Emacs message, whats the most convenient way to do this in emacs that uses the terminal?

```el
(printf "some number %d some string %s" 1 "test")
```

Comment: Note that this will not be possible on Windows or macOS as the app does not start from a terminal and so has no stdout etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro provides an equivilant to C's `printf` or Python's `print`:

```el
(defmacro printf (fmt &rest args)
  `(princ (format ,fmt ,@args) #'external-debugging-output))
```

Or as a function:

```el
(defun printf (&rest args)
  (princ (apply #'format args) #'external-debugging-output))
```